# Wordpad in Win 7: How to change the default font and size?

Tags: fonts, wordpad

When I open a new Win 7 Wordpad doc and start typing, the font is size 11 Calibri.  Is there a way to change the default in a newly opened doc to size 12 Verdana?

Answer (score 5):

## Quick analysis

When creating a blank document, WordPad uses a predefined font. In Windows 7 and later, it will use one of the following, depending on the system locale:

- **Aparajita, 11 pt**
- **Arial, 10 pt**
- **Arial, 11 pt**
- **Calibri, 11 pt**
- **CordiaUPC, 14 pt**
- **DaunPenh, 16 pt**
- **DokChampa, 12 pt**
- **Estrangelo Edessa, 10 pt**
- **Iskoola Pota, 11 pt**
- **Kalinga, 11 pt**
- **Kartika, 11 pt**
- **Malgun Gothic, 10 pt**
- **Microsoft Himalaya, 16 pt**
- **Microsoft Yi Baiti, 12 pt**
- **Mongolian Baiti, 14 pt**
- **MS Mincho, 11 pt**
- **MV Boli, 10 pt**
- **PMingLiU, 11 pt**
- **Raavi, 11 pt**
- **Shonar Bangla, 11 pt**
- **Shruti, 11 pt**
- **SimSun, 11 pt**
- **Sylfaen, 10 pt**
- **Tunga, 11 pt**
- **Vani, 11 pt**
- **Vijaya, 11 pt**

Those fonts are hard-coded in the `wordpad.exe.mui` resource file. When opening plain text (`.txt`) files, the font will be automatically set to **Courier New**. WordPad doesn't provide a way to customize either behavior.

### Further reading

- [WordPad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPad)
- [About Multilingual User Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317706%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

---

## Handmade customization

With some work you can bend the rules, and pick a custom font. The following steps apply to Window 7 and later.

1. Download and install [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/).
2. Create a new WordPad document, and check what's the default font displayed. Then close all WordPad instances.
3. Navigate to the WordPad folder, which is usually located here:

   ```
    C:\Program Files\Windows NT\Accessories
   ```
4. Locate and open the folder named after a [culture name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb896001.aspx) which matches your system locale (e.g. `en-US` for US English).
5. Copy the `wordpad.exe.mui` file to the desktop, and rename it to `wordpad2.exe.mui`.
6. Start ResHacker, click **File > Open**, choose the **All files (`*.*`)** type, and select the file you copied earlier.
7. Expand the folder called `23` in the right pane, and then expand its subfolder which should be named `40124`. Click the item available there.
8. Select all text, copy it, and paste into a blank Notepad document.
9. Open the replace dialog by clicking **Edit > Replace**. Let's say you want to replace **Calibri, 11 pt** with **Verdana, 12 pt**. In that case you would use the following find/replace strings:

   *Find what*

   ```
   size="220" fontFace="Calibri"
   ```

   *Replace with*

   ```
   size="240" fontFace="Verdana"
   ```

   The font size can be calculated by multiplying the size in points by `20` and omitting the unit: **11 pt** becomes `220`, **12 pt** becomes `240`, and so on.
10. After replacing everything, select all the text, copy it, and go back to Resource Hacker.
11. Delete the original text, replace the it with the edited one, and click the **Compile Script** button.

    If you also want to change the font associated with `.txt` files, expand the `String Table` folder, expand its first subfolder (which should be called `7`), and then change the string associated with number `111`. When you're done, click the **Compile Script** button.
12. Save the changes by clicking **File > Save**, and close Resource Hacker.
13. Put the `wordpad2.exe.mui` in the same folder where `wordpad.exe.mui` is.
14. Open an [elevated command prompt](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/command-prompt-faq#1TC=windows-7), and type or paste the following commands pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> each time. Make sure to replace `xx-YY` with the correct folder name you retrieved in step 4.

    ```
    cd /d "%programfiles%\Windows NT\Accessories\xx-YY" 
    takeown /f wordpad.exe.mui /a
    icacls wordpad.exe.mui /grant:r *S-1-5-32-544:F
    ren wordpad.exe.mui wordpad.exe.mui.old
    ren wordpad2.exe.mui wordpad.exe.mui
    ```

    Changes are applied immediately.

### Screeshots

#### Before

[image: Screenshot 1]

#### After

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: This is a good procedure but on Windows 7 SP1 changes to the .mui file seem to have no effect. You have to do one more non-intuitive step: Turn a Windows feature off in the Windows Features control panel, such as "Windows Gadget Platform". This requires a reboot, after which you can immediately turn it back on. This took me many hours to figure out, was inspired by this page http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/126315-welcome-log-text-message-change.html

Comment: Also note this works on Windows 10, without needing the "features" trick. Not sure if the exact shell commands shown work, I used the GUI to change permissions.

Answer (score 1):

I think a quick google may solve that issue. [First google result](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/want-to-change-wordpad-defaults-for-font-type-size/a99d61f2-1bc7-4f98-ba98-a30acc932e16)

Quoting:

> One of the easiest is to open Worpad and type one character.
>
> Select the character and set all of the options to what you normally
>   use. Save the file as the default .rtf for Wordpad.
>
> You can now use that file as a template for opening Wordpad with all
>   of your preferred options selected.
>
> If you have Wordpad pinned to the Taskbar, right click the Wordpad
>   icon and you should see the file you just created in the Recent list.
>   Click the 'Pushpin' icon on that file to pin the template to the
>   Wordpad jumplist to keep it handy.

Comment: You might want to include the essential parts of the answer in your answer. Link only answers may go stale, if say, microsoft decided to change their URL scheme.

Comment: @arielnmz An answer below the one you quote is:

Comment: The answer quoted by @arielnmz is called in other anwsers in that MS Community forum both a "kludge" and a "workaround". Please see the answer there by ptsome110, who claims he's "finally found a true solution, not a work around!" I'd like to try his idea out, but unfortunately the path he mentions in step 2 has been elided to "%userprofile%\AppData\Roamin… Explorer\Quick Launch". Could someone here figure out what that path should be? Thanks.

Comment: It's been a long time since I last used windows but I think the path is `%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\Quick Launch`.

Comment: @NotSuper That's just a slighty different way to achieve the same workaround.

Comment: @arielnmz that gets me "Path doesn't exist".

Comment: As the user said above, that's another way to achieve the dame result.

Comment: Just a note: oftentimes I can't find any help, even with Google. I just solved a similar problem (after finding no help) and I'm about to ask / answer the question here if no one else has already.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved a similar problem of my own with WordPad: changes I made wouldn't take as defaults. I ran WordPad as Administrator, and it saved the changes first try.